# Access class member pointer

Tags: c++, class, pointers, sdl

I am writing several classes in C++ that is an overlay to common SDL 2 functions.

Class A holds the SDL window data and manipulates it

```
class A 
{
  protected:
    SDL_Window *window;

  public:
    SDL_Window* get_window(){ return window; }
};
```

Class B handles the Renderer management and needs access to SDL window data

```
class B : public A
{
  private:
    ...
  public:
    /** 
        This is the functions that access 
        the window data
    */
    void create_renderer( int index, Uint32 flags );
};

void B::create_renderer( int index, Uint32 flags )
{

  /**
     Input window data:
      The window data from class A, see the section "I have tried:"
       To see what I have tried to do to get the window data
  */
  SDl_CreateRenderer( (Input window data ), index, flags );
}
```

The problem is this, when I go to access the window data from class A in class B in the function create_renderer() and then feed that window data into the desired function( SDL_CreateRenderer( ... ) ) I get a segfault in SDL_CreateRenderer(...). This is because the wrong address for the window data is being feed into it.

I have tried:

```
this->window;
this->get_window();
window
get_window();
```

These all result in the segfault

The problem is that I can't get it to access the memory location were the window data is at.

When I run my debuger, the memory address of the window data is different then the one being feed into the function when using the methods I specified above. The problem is in
the method in which I am tring to get the window data.

I know that you feed the window data into create_renderer() by using functions arguments but in grand scheme of the project this would be silly as the two class are tied together and would make the user do a lot of unnecessary work.

How do I get class B to access the window data in class A?

How I access class A and B:

```
class Overlord
{
   A a;
   B b;
};

Overlord overlord;

overlord.b.create_renderer( -1, 0 );
```

That is the basics of how I access class B and the function create_renderer(). Like I have said class A and class B are part of a large class scheme that is outside the scope of this question. Hope this helps.

Comment: Show your _actual_ function definition for `A::get_window()`, and `B::create_renderer()`.

Comment: Also, the code as posted would fail for some trivial reasons (missing return types). Please, write a small test that represents your issue and copy-paste it into the question. More often than not, when typing into the web interface you will make mistakes and change the code in ways that will make it not match your problem.

Comment: @David Rodriguez The problem has to do with the way to use C++ not the code. The code I put up their is give a visual of way communing my idea.

Comment: @Chad get_window() for A is just "return window" as it says. Plus create_renderer() does a lot more that is outside the scope of this question. If I can get it to access the window data from class 
A then I will be good

Comment: @drCoding: The code (if it was as the question) should work with any of the four options, which means that it is not an issue with the language in general but with your particular code in particular, and unless you post the exact code (and the error messages), this cannot be answered (I am voting to close now).

Comment: This EXAMPLE code is part of a large project that is undocumented and complex. It is also beyond the scope of the question which is how do access the window data in class A from class B

Comment: @drCoding: I think what everyone is trying to explain to you is that there's nothing wrong with the code you've shown us, so the problem must be in the code you're not showing us. Insisting that the problem is in this code snippet isn't going to help you solve your problem. Showing the actual code is more likely to do that. Several things can cause code to appear to malfunction in the way you describe: Not setting the window member correctly, a buffer overflow corrupting it after it has been set, etc. Also, it's generally considered bad style to break encapsulation the way you do in class A.

Comment: How do you create the `B` object, and how do you access it? Maybe it's because of [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing)? Make a small example that shows this behavior, and you can post the whole code. See http://sscce.org/

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I could not go to sscce.org but I did add a small example that shows how I access the two class in casse of object slicing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you initialize your `window` class member? This may be at the root of the problem.

Just a suspicion (or "psychic debugging", [as Raymond Chen would call it](http://blogs.msdn.com/search/searchresults.aspx?q=psychic%20debugging&sections=2905)), but is it possible that you're initializing `window` in the `a` member of your `Overlord` class, then expecting the same `window` pointer to show up in the `b` member of `Overlord`? It's not quite clear to me why `Overlord` has to contain an instance of both `A` and `B`, since `B` inherits from `A`. Maybe you're misunderstanding how inheritance of data members works in C++?

Comment: Overlord contains an instance of both A and B because that way the class can be chained together for the users convince so that they don't have load a ton of class. I think that this a flaw in the code design and I am going to go and rethink it